# How to avoid only BottomNavbar to pushed up when soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-bottomnav

I have a view like this in my android app

[image]

There is a `mainActivity` which has that `bottomNavBar` and there is fragment inside activity which has two buttons at bottom.

What I am supposed to do is that when soft keyboard appears `bottomNavBar` should stay at bottom (behind the keyboard) but those two buttons should be pushed up and visible on top of keyboard

If I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for mainActivity in `manifest` file then keyboard push up bottomNavBar and buttons aswell.

If I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` only to fragment (programmatically) then it still shows same behavior.

How can I do that? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Here is my Activity xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
            android:layout_weight="@integer/int_two"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="@integer/int_zero"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Did you try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also face the same problem, after putting multiple efforts I find a solution which work for me.What I do, when **keyboard appers** make **bottomNavBar** visibility **GONE** and **vice-versa**.

Try this for getting keyboard **open** and **closed** event -

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
      Rect r = new Rect();
      view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
      if (view.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top) > 500) {
        // on Keyboard Open
        llBottomNavBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } else {
        // on keyboard close
        llBottomNavBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });
```

For getting view I use

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_abc, null);
```

Comment: it worked thanks, but can you please tell me why we are using value 500?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. I tried your layout. Add to you manifest on the appropriate activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`
Note this also affects FABs and other anchor views

```xml
<activity
   android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I have updated question for you. You can see activity code